# Is there any way to include heatmap in treemap

Tags: highcharts

I want to include heatmaps on each treamap area.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set color for individual treemap data point as a linear gradient. For example:

```
series: [{
  type: "treemap",
  data: [..., {
    name: 'Rick',
    value: 10,
    color: {
      linearGradient: {
        x1: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y1: 0,
        y2: 1
      },
      stops: [
        [0, '#ffc400'],
        [0.3, '#00ff62'],
        [1, '#00306e']
      ]
    }
  }]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0usv9npa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.data.color

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors